# My app stops responding but doesn't throw an ANR, need help debugging

Tags: java, android

Basically everything points to my app being frozen and yet no errors are thrown when debugging and an ANR is no where to be seen.  It doesn't respond to touch but on top of that I have a fps counter in the draw function that stops showing up in logcat after it freezes.  First time I've ran across something like this where I don't know how to find the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are running some network operation or any other heavy operation on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

If the logcat stops outputting from the app and there is no ANR, I would hazard a guess that the problem is that the onDraw() function is failing to be called, and so the canvas isn't being redrawn and onTouch() isn't being called when you touch the screen.

If you are using SurfaceView, is it implementing SurfaceHolder correctly?

Comment: Yes using SurfaceView/Holder and as far as I know they are implemented perfectly.  It's been working great, only recently I put in these color transitions and they seem to work for a while and then it will freeze.  I suppose I'm overloading the thread to the point it just gives up?  I just tried putting in trace statements in the pause() and stop() functions in the thread.  I can't even seem to pinpoint exactly where the thread is stopping.

Comment: Well if it works without what you recently put in, then you have a good idea of where the problem lies. If you showed a code sample it might be easier to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

When that's happened to me, it's because it's hit a break-point in my code.  That's probably just me, though.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was an infinite loop and because it wasn't the main thread getting hung up, an ANR didn't appear.

I simply had to update DDMS through Eclipse where I could profile what was taking up all the CPU resources when it'd freeze.